# Apply groupBy and orderBy on a dataframe in scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement to order a column value and group another column in dataframe.

Data in the dataframe is as shown below.

```
+------------+---------+-----+
|      NUM_ID|    TIME |SIG_V|
+------------+---------+-----+
|XXXXX01     |167499000|55   |
|XXXXX02     |167499000|     |
|XXXXX01     |167503000|     |
|XXXXX02     |179810000| 81.0|
|XXXXX02     |179811000| 81.0|
|XXXXX01     |179833000|     |
|XXXXX02     |179833000|     |
|XXXXX02     |179841000| 81.0|
|XXXXX01     |179841000|     |
|XXXXX02     |179842000| 81.0|
|XXXXX03     |179843000| 87.0|
|XXXXX02     |179849000|     |
|XXXXX02     |179850000|     |
|XXXXX01     |179850000| 88.0|
|XXXXX01     |179857000|     |
|XXXXX01     |179858000|     |
|XXXXX01     |179865000|     |
|XXXXX03     |179865000|     |
|XXXXX02     |179870000|     |
|XXXXX02     |179871000| 11  |
+--------------------+-------+
```

The above data is already ordered by **TIME** column.

My requirement is to group the **NUM_ID** column as shown below.

```
+------------+---------+-----+
|      NUM_ID|    TIME |SIG_V|
+------------+---------+-----+
|XXXXX01     |167499000|55   |
|XXXXX01     |167503000|     |
|XXXXX01     |179833000|     |
|XXXXX01     |179841000|     |
|XXXXX01     |179850000| 88.0|
|XXXXX01     |179857000|     |
|XXXXX01     |179858000|     |
|XXXXX01     |179865000|     |
|XXXXX02     |167499000|     |
|XXXXX02     |179810000| 81.0|
|XXXXX02     |179811000| 81.0|
|XXXXX02     |179833000|     |
|XXXXX02     |179841000| 81.0|
|XXXXX02     |179849000|     |
|XXXXX02     |179850000|     |
|XXXXX02     |179842000| 81.0|
|XXXXX02     |179870000|     |
|XXXXX02     |179871000| 11  |
|XXXXX03     |179843000| 87.0|
|XXXXX03     |179865000|     |
+--------------------+-------+
```

The column **NUM_ID** is grouped now and the column **TIME** is in sorted order for each **NUM_ID**.

I tried applying groupBy and orderBy to a dataframe which is not working.

```
val df2 =  df1.withColumn("SIG_V", col("SIG")).orderBy("TIME").groupBy("NUM_ID")
```

and getting the error while df2.show

```
error: value orderBy is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset
```

Any leads to obtain the requirement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `groupBy`, just put the two columns in `orderBy`:

```
scala> df.show()
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  1|  3|
|  2|  2|
|  1|  4|
|  1|  1|
|  2|  0|
|  1| 10|
|  2|  5|
+---+---+


scala> df.orderBy('_1,'_2).show()
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  1|  1|
|  1|  3|
|  1|  4|
|  1| 10|
|  2|  0|
|  2|  2|
|  2|  5|
+---+---+
```